# Is chlorophyll living or non living?

Tags: botany

Is chlorophyll living or non living, and after boiling the water out of a chlorophyll extract would it still live, as in would it still maintain its properties after re-adding liquid to the dried chlorophyll?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you want to know about chlorophyl or about plants? Chlorophyl is just a chemical contained for instance in plant cells.

Comment: If you meant "chloroplasts" rather than "chlorophyl", there might be an interesting debate, cf. Richard Smith's answer here about cyanobacteria as being almost "free-living chloroplasts" http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/photosynthetic-pigments-vs-chloroplasts/2850#2850

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chlorophyll is [organic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_compound), not living, which is a fancy way of saying that it contains carbon. As for your question about boiling, it depends on whether or not the heat from boiling will disrupt the chemical bonds and destroy the molecule. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_a), chlorophyll a will melt at around 117°C (I'll assume that chlorophyll b is similar), which is higher than the boiling point of water, so if the temperature is strictly maintained, the chemical should stay intact.